# JWPlayer + youtube = Green Square in Background

Tags: javascript, youtube, flash, jwplayer

Im embedding a youtube video in JWPlayer like this:

```
<embed src="fileadmin/templates/web/js/jwplayer/player.swf"
   width="300"
   height="225"
   bgcolor="transparent"
   allowscriptaccess="always"
   allowfullscreen="true"
   flashvars="file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Bmhjf0rKe8&skin=fileadmin/templates/web/js/jwplayer/skin/bekle.xml"
   />
```

But when i load the video I have a gren square for 2 seconds while the video loads and then the video is over it, but you can see some green margins to the side of the video. How could i remove this???

Here's the video: http://bwp-dev2.wedo-projects.de/

Comment: The site you linked to requests authentication...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered something like this before, and it was a hardware acceleration issue in Flash at the time. I'm not 100% certain as I can't access your page due to requiring authentication, but I'd recommend just trying to disable hardware acceleration. There's a link [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html) to Adobe's site with details on how to disable it. Once you disable it, try viewing the video again.

There are some forum posts it appears with other people reporting a similar issue:

[480p Green Screen - Youtube Help](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=71c369eaa337746c&hl=en)

**UPDATE** - Here are some additional links that support this answer:

[Videos showing green??](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=1e5e37600a76ce74&hl=en)

[Green screen in youtube (Solved/Closed)](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-341150-green-screen-in-youtube)

[How to – Youtube Screen goes green](http://tech.xnepali.com/how-to-youtube-screen-goes-green/)